# jquery find text nodes within an element and join and wrap with a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie and am having a hard time with some text that has no element, I am trying to wrap text outside of a tag with a list tag :

http://jsfiddle.net/danb/7xu6A/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    text <br>to wrap and combine        
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

This was working for me until I came across some instances where the string was broken with a 
 tag - even if i take out the `<br>` first they are still separate nodes and get wrapped as such.

```
$('ul').contents().remove('br')
       .filter(function()
       {
           return (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.data) !== '');
       }).wrap('<li class="nav current"></li>');
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This is obviously invalid markup. `<ul>` element should contain *only* `<li>` elements inside.

Comment: This is invalid HTML, so there is no _conventional_ method to solving this issue. It can be solved, but invalid markup is the stepping stone to inefficient code.

Comment: I assume you have no control over the markup?

Comment: Thanks, i am aware of the markup problem, but unfortunately it is dynamically generated and for reasons well beyond my control cannot be fixed at this point

Comment: @user1649172 Try `wrapAll`. Possibly it helps.

Comment: I'd probably do something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7xu6A/19/) if I could'nt change the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution (assume your ul has an id of "whatever" in this example)

Your final wrapped text is stored in the variable 'finaltext'

**NOTE:** Uncommenting the commented lines will also remove the text "text to wrap and combine" from your page, and then also append "text to wrap and combine" as a new list item, and finally, take out the br tag!

```
var d = document.getElementById("whatever");

var nds = d.childNodes;

var finaltext = "";

$(nds).each(function(){

   var trmdvl = $.trim(this.nodeValue);

   if(trmdvl){
      finaltext += trmdvl + " ";
      //$(this).remove(); 
   }
});

//$(d).append("<li>" + $.trim(finaltext) + "</li>");
//$('br').remove();
```

Assumed HTML Below:

```
<ul id="whatever">
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    text <br>to wrap and combine        
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```